# How to update existing SparkSession instance or create a new one in spark-shell?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I launch `spark-shell`, it creates an instance of `SparkSession`. However, I should create it as follows:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
                        .config("es.nodes",elasticHost)
                        .config("es.port",elasticPort)
                        .config("es.nodes.wan.only","true")
                        .appName("Test")
                        .getOrCreate()
```

How can I update the existing `spark` in `spark-shell` or create the new one as I showed above?

Comment: Well you can do `spark-shell --conf blah=blah` if that works for you

Answer (score 10):

You can set the configuration properties using [SparkSession.conf.set](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.RuntimeConfig@set(key:String,value:String):Unit) or create another `SparkSession` instance using [SparkSession.newSession](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@newSession():org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession) and then set the properties.

> **set(key: String, value: String): Unit** Sets the given Spark runtime configuration property.
>
> **newSession(): SparkSession** Start a new session with isolated SQL configurations, temporary tables, registered functions are isolated, but sharing the underlying SparkContext and cached data.

Both ways work (almost) the same with the difference that you can temporarily set a property to a new value and use both `SparkSession`s simultaneously.

```
// hello property is not set
scala> spark.conf.getOption("hello")
res1: Option[String] = None

scala> spark.conf.set("hello", "world")

// hello property is set
scala> spark.conf.getOption("hello")
res3: Option[String] = Some(world)

// create a new SparkSession (so you'll have two at the same time)
val ns = spark.newSession

// hello is not set in a new session
scala> ns.conf.getOption("hello")
res4: Option[String] = None

ns.conf.set("hello", "hello in another session")

scala> ns.conf.getOption("hello")
res8: Option[String] = Some(hello in another session)

// the value of hello in the initial SparkSession remains unchanged
scala> spark.conf.getOption("hello")
res9: Option[String] = Some(world)
```